# How to control the screen resolution

Tags: android

Whenever i run my program in emulator, the pixels and screen resolutions are displays perfectly. but at the same time when install the apk in basic version of android mobile, the resolution will changed. Its getting some nasty GUI formate. I am not sure how to rectify this issue. I did my application in 2.2 and i am using android Samsung 2.1 mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And your emulator and actual device (which is what, Samsung has a ton of Android devices) have probably different resolutions/screen densities.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create a few AVDs (in emulator) with different [resolution and density](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). So you should  be able to reproduce your issue on emulator. Or provide more info about layout etc.